# Powershell write variable to stdout as running

Tags: powershell, variables

In my powershell script I have a variable which captures its commands output

$files= dosomething

so running dosomething alone will produce output to the stdout. My question is how do I get that same functionality out of my variable as its running? mostly as a way to see progress.

maybe best to run the command and then somehow capture that to a variable?

UPDATE 1:

here's the command I'm trying to monitor:

```
$remotefiles = rclone md5sum remote: --dry-run --max-age "$lastrun" --filter-from "P:\scripts\filter-file.txt"
```

UPDATE 2:
running `rclone md5sum remote: --dry-run --max-age "$lastrun" --filter-from "P:\scripts\filter-file.txt"` directly produces output ...

Comment: Some cmdlets have an `-OutVariable` parameter.

Comment: I'm not running a cmdlet just an actual command so no -OutVariable

Comment: all the options seem to only work with cmdlets

Comment: Do you mean an expression of some sort? "*Commands*" in powershell are referred to as **cmdlets** (*command line utilities*).

Comment: @AbrahamZinala yes? updated the question with the exact command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to **enclose your assignment in `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), which passes the result of the assignment *through*; e.g:

```sh
# Enclosing an assignment in (...) passes the value that is assigned through.
PS> ($date = Get-Date)

Friday, May 21, 2021 7:43:48 PM
```

Note:

- **Use of `(...)` implies that all command output is captured *first*, before passing it through**; that is, you won't see the passed-through output until after the command has *terminated* - see the bottom section  for a solution.
- An assignment by default captures only *success* output (from *PowerShell* commands) / *stdout* output (from *external* commands).
- **If you (also) want to capture *error-stream* / *stderr* output**, **use `2>&1`** to merge the error-stream / stderr output into the success stream / stdout (see the conceptual [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) topic); in the case of the external `rclone` program (for brevity, the actual arguments are omitted and represented with placeholder `...`):

```sh
# Merge stderr into stdout and capture the combination, and also pass it through.
([string[]] $remotefiles = rclone ... 2>&1)
```

<sup>Note: the `[string[]]` type constraint ensures that the *stderr* lines too are captured as *strings*; by default, PowerShell returns them as [`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances. If you want *pipeline logic*, i.e. to only capture a `[string]` *scalar* if there's only *one* output line and use an array only for *multiple* lines, use

`($remotefiles = rclone ... 2>&1 | % ToString)` instead.</sup>

---

As [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) points out, PowerShell *cmdlets* (including [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) functions and scripts), support the **[common `-OutVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#outvariable)**, which also allows capturing a cmdlet's success output in addition to outputting it to the success output stream:

```sh
# Outputs *and* saves in variable $date.
# Note that the -OutVariable argument must *not* start with "$"
PS> Get-Date -OutVariable date

Friday, May 21, 2021 7:43:48 PM
```

Note: Using `2>&1` does *not* cause the `-OutVariable` to also capture error-stream output, but you can capture errors *separately*, using the [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#errorvariable).

**Caveat**: Surprisingly, **the `-OutVariable` target variable<sup>[1]</sup> *always* receives a [`[System.Collections.ArrayList]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) instance**, which is unusual in two respects:

- PowerShell generally uses regular [*array*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array) (`[object[]]`) instances to collect multiple output objects, such as in an *assignment*.
- While difference in (read-only) access between an array list and a regular array will rarely matter, the more problematic aspect is that an array list is used *even when the cmdlet outputs just ONE object*, unlike in *assignments*; in the case at hand this means:

  - `$date = Get-Date` stores a `[datetime]` instance in variable `$date`
  - whereas `Get-Date -OutVariable date` stores a single-element *array list* containing a `[datetime]` instance in `$date`.
- This unexpected behavior is the subject of [GitHub issue #3154](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3154).

---

By contrast, **[`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object)'s `-Variable`** parameter, as shown in [SADIK KUZU's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67644791/45375), does *not* exhibit this unexpected behavior; that is, it **behaves the same way as an *assignment***.

However, given that use of `Tee-Object` is by definition an *additional* call and therefore requires an extra pipeline segment, you do pay a performance penalty (though that may not matter in practice).

---

**Solution for a *long-running (external) command* whose output should be passed through *as it is being produced*:**

```sh
# Merge stderr into stdout and output in streaming fashion,
# while capturing the (stringified) lines in variable $remoteFiles
rclone ... 2>&1 | % ToString -OutVariable remoteFiles
```

Note: `%` is the built-in alias for the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet; `ToString` calls the `.ToString()` method on each object, which is necessary for converting the *stderr* output lines to strings, because PowerShell by default wraps them in[`[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances; if conversion to strings isn't desired or necessary, replace
`% ToString -OutVariable remoteFiles` with
`Tee-Object -Variable remoteFiles`.

---

<sup>[1] The same applies to the other common `-*Variable` parameters, such as `-ErrorVariable`.</sup>

Comment: @Daniel, yes, there are many useful PowerShell behaviors that are neither obvious nor (well-)documented.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I use this often in if statements like `if ($files = Get-ChildItem) { ... }`, just never thought about what it is actually doing.  Good stuff.  As always, thanks for your knowledge.  It's good to have a few people with PhDs in Powershell around here.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala: Honestly, I don't remember, it's been too long. However, the behavior _should_ be explained in the conceptual [about_Assignment_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators) help topic. I encourage you to open an issue at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues (you can directly create an issue from any help topic page) to ask them to add it (personally, [I've run out of steam](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/10238#issuecomment-830406280) contributing there).

Answer (score 3):

[Tee-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-2--output-processes-to-a-variable-and--select-object-) saves command output in a file or variable and also sends it down the pipeline.

```
Get-Process notepad | Tee-Object -Variable proc | Select-Object processname,handles

ProcessName                              Handles
-----------                              -------
notepad                                  43
notepad                                  37
notepad                                  38
notepad                                  38
```

This example gets a list of the processes running on the computer, saves them to the `$proc` variable, and pipes them to `Select-Object`.

Answer (score 1):

`Out-Host` will send output to the console without sending it down the pipe

```
Function Test-Output {
    param()
    $list = @(
        'Dogs',
        'Cats',
        'Monkeys'
    )

    $list | Out-Host
    $list | Select-Object -First 1
}

$output = Test-Output

# When running the line above Dogs, Cats, and Monkeys will display in the console
# Dogs
# Cats
# Monkeys

# However the variable $output will only contain 'Dogs'
$output
# Dogs
```